# centos6.6 in Dockerfile gives error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to use centos6.6 in Dockerfile,
I tried following both lines one by one in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:centos6.6
FROM centos:6.6
```

But getting this error while running docker:

```
root@onl-dev:/distros/trial# docker run -it trial
docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Can someone suggest me if I am missing anything here?

Comment: How did you build the trial image?

Comment: I have built it using "docker build -t trial ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear: you haven't specified a command to run, either in your `Dockerfile` or on the command line.  You could try:

```
docker run -it trial bash
```

...if you want a shell.  Or you could add to your `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD ["bash"]
```

...and now your image would run this by default if no command is provided on the command line.

Comment: In theory, [CentOS base image](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/939b4dc62009b1cdc3857f19996b1fd749b047f7/docker/Dockerfile) already specifies bash as the CMD